# Are multiple cpu cores are used in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
def count(n):
    while n > 0:
        n -= 1

count(100000000)
count(100000000)
```

In this case will this program run on multiple cores?

Comment: No, not unless you specifically implement multiprocessing. Your example will run in a single thread on a single core.

Comment: No.  See the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#module-multiprocessing) module.

Comment: Why would you think it would use multiple cores?

Comment: I don't think this question is really suited to this site

Comment: jamylak should i ask it on facebook?